# Store some data in client side which can be accessed across angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am new to angularjs. At the start of the app I need to hit the API and store some data in the client side so that it should be accessible across all the controllers and also in config.

Can you please suggest whats the best approach.

Here is what I have tried:

**Service**: My issue with it is every time I call , it will call the API.

I want to call only once and store it. I am fine with calling on page refresh.

**Value**: Cannot be accessed in config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in angular js `localstorage`.

Ypu can add data in `localstorage` and get them anywhere in the app , also if you want ,you can remove from `localstorage` also. 
Example

```
localStorage.setItem('test', data.item);
localStorage.getItem('test')
localStorage.removeItem('test');
```